# Laravel Homestead error: Failed to create host-only adaptor

Tags: php, laravel, virtualbox, laravel-5, homestead

This error occurs with all Vagrant boxes with a private network IP.

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *,int,int *)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I've tried composer install, manual install, downgrading virtualbox to 4.2.x - nothing works.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a common 'issue' on Windows 7 hosts with any vagrant box with a private network.

The Windows host user account needs to have admin rights.

Comment: My host user account is admin, UAC is down to zero, still geting this problem. Any idea? Win10/Vbox5

Comment: Win 10 has a different issue. Commenting out the private IP and add a port forward 80->4567. Then navigate to to http://localist:4567 instead works for me

Answer (score 0):

There's a known [bug # 14040](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040) in VirtualBox 5. Updating to [Vbox 5.0.9](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had  the same problem using virtualbox 5.0.26 when I updated to 5.1.4 it worked! am using vagrant version 1.9.1